# Cannot read property 'dtInstance' of undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-datatables

I am following this guide: https://stackblitz.com/edit/datatable-destory?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

It works wonderfully in Stackblitz. But when I use it in my own I get this error:

> Cannot read property 'dtInstance' of undefined

This is how I implement it:

**ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { DataTableDirective } from 'angular-datatables';

export class Test {
  constructor(
    public code: string,
    public name: string
  ) { }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-user-template',
  templateUrl: './user-template.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./user-template.component.css']
})
export class UserTemplateComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild(DataTableDirective) datatableElement: DataTableDirective;

  clients = Array<Test>();
  dtTrigger: Subject<any> = new Subject();
  dtOptions: DataTables.Settings = {};

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.dtOptions = {
      order: [[0, "asc"]],
      autoWidth: true,
      columns: [
        { title: 'Code', data: 'name' },
        { title: 'Name', data: 'code' },
      ]
    };

    this.clients.push(new Test("a", "a"));
    this.rerender();
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.dtTrigger.unsubscribe();
  }

  rerender(): void {
      this.datatableElement.dtInstance.then((dtInstance: DataTables.Api) => {
        dtInstance.destroy();
        this.dtTrigger.next();
      });
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.dtTrigger.next();
    this.datatableElement.dtInstance.then((dtInstance: DataTables.Api) => {
      dtInstance.columns().every(function () {
        const that = this;
        $('input', this.footer()).on('keyup change', function () {
          if (that.search() !== this['value']) {
            that.search(this['value']).draw();
          }
        });
      });
    });
  }

  addRow() {
    this.clients.push(new Test("ac", "ac"));
    this.rerender();
  }

  removeRow() {
    this.clients = this.clients.slice(1);
    this.rerender();
  }

}
```

**html**

```
<table #ref datatable [dtOptions]="dtOptions" [dtTrigger]="dtTrigger" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>code</th>
            <th>name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let client of clients">
            <td> {{client.code}} </td>
            <td> {{client.name}} </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>
                <input type="text" placeholder="code" name="search-code" />
            </th>
            <th>
                <input type="text" placeholder="name" name="search-name" />
            </th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
<br/>
<br/>
<div class="btn-group btn-group-justified">
    <a class="btn btn-default">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" (click)="addRow()">Creation</button>
    </a>
</div>
<div class="btn-group btn-group-justified">
    <a class="btn btn-default">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" (click)="removeRow()">Remove</button>
    </a>
</div>
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: The error message suggest that the viewchild it not working correctly. Can you try using static = true in the viewchild?  Like @ViewChild(DataTableDirective, {static: true]) datatableElement: DataTableDirective;

Comment: @Havald, still the same error Sir...

Answer (score 1):

Do you need to call  this.rerender(); in the ngOnInit? datatableElement won't be available in this hook. If you open console in the stackblitz you will also get an error.

Try commenting out this.rerender() in the ngOnInit.

Comment: Am sorry @David, I overlooked something. I forgot to write implement AfterViewInit. That was the issue. Thank you though...